# How to make whole Tkinter window scrollable

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I am working on a GUI and have added some labelframes which barely fits the window. I want to add a menubar so after adding it, the last labelframe does not fit the window. Hence I want to make it scrollable. I tried many solutions on internet but still not able to scroll.

Here is the GUI pic:
[image: scroll issue]

Here is the code. Not sending all label frames code since one will give the idea.

```
self.window = Tk()
    

self.color = 'dark orange'
    self.window.geometry('640x720')
    self.window.resizable(False, False)
    self.window.configure(background=self.color)
    self.window.title('Classify')
    #self.window.iconbitmap('py.ico')
    
    self.frame = Frame(self.window)
    self.frame.pack(expand=True, fill=BOTH)

    self.canvas = Canvas(self.frame,background='dark orange')

    self.v_scroll = Scrollbar(self.frame, orient=VERTICAL, command=self.canvas.yview,background='black',activebackground='black')
    self.v_scroll.pack(side=RIGHT,fill=Y)

    self.canvas['yscrollcommand'] = self.v_scroll.set
    self.canvas.pack(expand=True, fill=BOTH)

    self.frame2 = Frame(self.canvas,bg='dark orange')
    self.canvas.create_window((0, 0), window=self.frame2, anchor=N + W)

    self.menubar = Menu(self.frame2)
  
    # Adding File Menu and commands
    self.file = Menu(self.menubar, tearoff = 0)
    self.menubar.add_cascade(label ='File', menu = self.file)
    self.file.add_command(label ='New File', command = None)

    self.window.config(menu = self.menubar)

    self.frame = LabelFrame(self.canvas, text='File Selection', bg=self.color)
    self.frame.place(width=580, height=80, bordermode=OUTSIDE, x=20,y=10)
```

More labelframes are there having same procedure with different y coordinate only  are there but has same procedure so skipping to last lines.

```
self.window.update()
    self.canvas.configure(scrollregion=self.canvas.bbox(ALL))
    self.window.mainloop()
```

What changes should be done?

Comment: First you should create those `LabelFrame` inside `self.frame2` instead of `self.canvas`. Second use `.grid()` or `.pack()` instead of `.place()` on those frames because `.place()` will not adjust the size of the parent (i.e. `self.frame2`) so that it would not make the scrollbar active.

Comment: @acw1668 It worked. I am new to tkinter so did not know about this difference between place and grid. Thank you very much!